# How to scroll to bottom in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have list of comments. Every time user adds a new comment, I want that div and that div only to scroll to bottom. That div height is fixed and overflow is also set to scroll. I have found some answers to use dummy-div at the end of the comment list to scroll. I encountered 2 problems with that approach.

1. When used scrollIntoView to that div element, the entire body scrolls. Which is unwanted. I just want that div body to scroll to the last comment.
2. Say, I have a function, upon calling, scrolls to bottom. `handleScrollToBottom`. I called it right after the comment was added. But, it doesn't scroll to the bottom. Which makes sense. Because, if I am not wrong, updating the state doesn't  update the state instantly. Let me demonstrate more with code

```
  const Comment = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const handleScrollToBottom = () => {
    //
    ref.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  const addComment = () => {
    //
    setAllComments((pre) => [...pre, { cmt: newCmt }]);
    // Doesn't work here
    handleScrollToBottom();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {allComments.map((cmt) => (
        <Comment cmt={cmt} />
      ))}
      {/* Dummy Div to scroll to bottom */}
      <div ref={ref}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

That was the second problem. So, I used `useEffect` and put `allComments.length` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Deleting a comment calls this function
  handleScrollToBottom();
}, [allComments.length]);
```

That does work. But, the problem is, when a comment was deleted, it scrolls to bottom becasue the comments length changes which is not desired. Does anyone have any solution for my problem? I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, for sure. Just checked them. Will try out with code and accept the correct answer. Thanks to you all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly you want the scrolling to happen only when a new comment is added.

So can you create a react state that keeps track of only the added comments, if that changes then scroll, this would ignore deletes.

```
const [commentAdded, setCommentAdded] = useState(0)

const addComment = () => {

     setAllComments((pre) => [...pre, { cmt: newCmt }]);
     setCommentAdded(++commentAdded)
};


useEffect(() => {
     handleScrollToBottom();
 }, [commentAdded]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of using `state` to check if comments are added or removed, like [@wpw has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536639/16420018)**, you can add another `ref` to keep track of whether comments were added or deleted. And only trigger `scrollIntoView` when the `ref` reflects comments are added:

```
const Comment = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const commentsAddedRef = useRef(false); // Checks if comments are added or removed
  const handleScrollToBottom = () => {
    //
    ref.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  const addComment = () => {
    commentsAddedRef.current = true; // Set ref to true because comment is added
    setAllComments((pre) => [...pre, { cmt: newCmt }]);
  };

  const removeComment = () => {
    commentsAddedRef.current = false; // Set ref to false because comment is removed
    ...
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(commentsAddedRef.current){ // Only triggers if comments are added
      handleScrollToBottom();
    }
  }, [allComments]);

  return (
    <div>
      {allComments.map((cmt) => (
        <Comment cmt={cmt} />
      ))}
      {/* Dummy Div to scroll to bottom */}
      <div ref={ref}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't think running the useEffect with the allComments.length is a good idea, useEffect should trigger if a prop or state variable changed, the length of an array is not a good handle to run the effect.  But, he could try using a ref in some way, that sounds like a a good idea, using a ref though is a different approach than leaning on react state, not sure how it would impact the rest of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you use class component, then you can add a callback to the `setState` inside the `addComment` method.
This way there'll be no impact when a comment is deleted.

```
class CommentList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = createRef();
        this.state = {allComments: []};
    }

    scrollToBottom = () => {
        this.ref.current?.scrollIntoView();
    }

    addComment = () => {
        this.setState((state) => (
           {allComments: state.allComments.concat({ cmt: newCmt })}
        ), ()=> {
            scrollToBottom();
        });
    }

    render() {
       return <div>
           {
               this.state.allComments.map(c=><Comment cmt={c}>)
           } 
           <div ref={this.ref}></div></div>;
       </div>
    }
}
```